# Unexpected token export webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, config, babeljs

I have webpack config like this:

```
loaders: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
]
```

And babel config:

```
{
    "presets": ['es2015'],
    "plugins": ['transform-runtime']
}
```

But the browser shows this message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you actually install the preset using `npm install` or `yarn add`?

Comment: Might want to add `stage-0` to `presets`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack 2 `loaders` become `rules`

Answer (score 0):

If someone is finding their way into here. One solution may be to delete `node_modules` and rebuild it with `npm install`.